# Receiving POST data in Django from Vue

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am doing post request from `vue` and trying to collect the data in Django `views` But the part that receiving data in `views` isn't quite working.

here is `views.py`

```
from ..models import project

def insertProjects(request):

   projectModel = project.Project()

   if request.method == "POST":

      #projectModel.project_id = request.POST.get("project_id")
      #projectModel.project_name = request.POST.get("project_name")
      #projectModel.company_name = request.POST.get("company_name")
      #projectModel.save() 

      name = request.POST.get("project_name")
      print(name)

   return HttpResponse(True)
```

After vue `POST` request called. The `print()` is returns `None`? But request payload is not empty. And endpoint returns `200`

[image]

Any idea about this problem? How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Is your problem is than you are passing many informations in each keys of the request and your view.py is handling only the last item of each key?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is because you are passing many elements in each key of your request and the view.py is handling only the last element of each key, you should try to use getlist:

```
project_name_list = request.POST.getlist("project_name")
for name in project_name_list: 
    projectModel.project_name = name
```